# Rails Devise & Simple Form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4, devise and simple form.

The devise view has a standard remember me checkbox, which I am trying to format.

I read a blog post showing me how to alter the devise checkbox aligment for the remember me field (which as a standard pushes the checkbox to the left of the vertical alignment of the other fields in the form.

To fix this, I changed my framework_and_overrides.css.scss to include:

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Now, when I try to use the devise form, the checkbox appears on top of the letter 'R' in the remember me label.

Also, my css to style the words 'remember me' won't apply to that text.

My field currently has:

```
        <%= f.input :remember_me,  as: :boolean,  inline_label: true, :input_html => {:class => 'deviselabels'}, label: false if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
```

The styling I'm trying to apply is in the 'devise labels' class - it changes the font color and size. But it isn't working on this specific form element. It works fine on the other elements in the form and doesnt alter margins:

```
.deviselinks {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: white;
    a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:white;};
    a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:white;};
    a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:white;};
    a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:white;};

}
```

Does anyone know how to move the words 'remember me' over so they are to the left of the check box (rather than the 'R' being underneath the checkbox)?  Also, how do I apply my font styling to the words 'Remember me'?

The entire new session form is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

      <div class="devisetitle">Welcome back</div>
    </div>

  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, :html => {:id => "sign_in_user"}, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">


              <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>

                  <div class="facebookauth">
                    <%= link_to "Login with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
                  </div>

              <% end -%>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">


              <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>

                  <div class="googleauth">
                    <%= link_to "Login with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
                  </div>

              <% end -%>

            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

              <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
                  <div class="linkedinauth">
                    <%= link_to "Login with LinkedIn", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %>
                  </div>

              <% end -%>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>




        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="emailform">
            <div class="form-inputs", style="margin-left: 7%">


              <%= devise_error_messages! %>


                <%= f.input :email, :label_html => {:class => 'deviselabels'}, placeholder: 'Enter email',  autofocus: true, :input_html => {:maxlength => 25, :size => 40, class: 'lineitemdevise'} %>
                <%= f.input :password, :label_html => {:class => 'deviselabels'},  placeholder: 'At least 8 characters', :input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40, class: 'lineitemdevise'} %>

                <%= f.input :remember_me,  as: :boolean,  inline_label: true, :input_html => {:class => 'deviselabels'}, label: false if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>

           </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
              <%= f.button :submit, "Login", :class => "dcpb" %>
            </div>
  <% end %>

  </div>


  </div>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="loginredirect">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the exact HTML output of your form here? Oh, and did you use Bootstrap as an underlying Framework?

Comment: posted. i have used bootstrap, thanks for having a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the label text into a separate label tag. Something like:

```
<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me, "Remember Me", class: 'deviselabels' %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
<% end %>
```

This would make the `check_box` appear after the `label`. To make the `check_box` appear below, just add a `<br/>` in between them or add the `display: block;` styling to both of them. You can use the class `deviselabels` to style the text however you want.

Edit:

So Simple Form is a tool to make building forms easier. Your one line of code is equivalent to my four lines above, with the exception of the `label` and `check_box` being flipped. The reason for this is that that is the conventional way of displaying a label/checkbox combo (checkbox then label).

That being said, there is another way of achieving this, though one not as "clean", IMO. You could give the `check_box` the style `position: absolute` and play with the `top` style (i.e. `top: 20px`). You might have to give the parent element the style `position: relative` to make it work. As I said, not as clean, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks Ryan - I'll go with your suggestion and move on. I was really hoping to understand what's broken.

Comment: i have to wait 6 hours to give you the bounty

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand any of that. I wanted to know why the checkbox (in my attempt) appears over the top of the 'R'. I have separated them - but I'm not clear on what was causing that problem

Comment: You mean directly on top (like covering) or just above the 'R'?

Comment: Covering - im using inline styling - so the box is supposed to be to the left of the label. Instead, I concealed the 'R'. This is attributable to the framework override I made - so that the checkbox as left aligned with all of my other form elements (it sits to the left of the outer left border otherwise).

Comment: Hmmm. The only other advice I could give you is to play around with the `margin-top` or the `top` styles on the checkbox. One of them should push the box down.

Comment: No - I'm afraid we're talking at cross purposes now. The check box should be horizontally aligned with the words 'remember me'. There are other SO posts which identify that Simple Form or Bootstrap puts a -20px margin on the left of the check box. I have overriden that. Instead of moving the whole thing across so that the check box and the text are spaced as they were previously, it keeps the text where it was and puts the box on top of the 'R'.